# Error en la consola de Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

En un programa que estoy realizando en eclipse me piden que cree un setter que devuelva verdadero o falso cuando el numero introducido sea negativo, mi setter es el siguiente:

```
public boolean personas(int persona) {

    if(personas<0) {

        return false;

    }else {

        this.personas=personas;
        return true;
    }
```

Pero en la consola, al ejecutar y poner un numero negativo, se vuelve "loco" imprimiendo mensajes ¿eso a que es debido?

Gracias.

Comment: Qué mensajes imprime?

Comment: if(numero!=4){    
    
    try{
     /*
     System.in.read();
    }catch(IOException enterError){
     System.err.println("[ERROR] Keyboard input throwed an exception!!");
    }

Comment: Entiendo que es por esa función pero es normal que se repita sin parar?

Comment: No estás poniendo el código que provoca el error, añade el código del método que llama a este *setter* (que debería llamarse setPersonas y no devolver nada, si quieres seguir las convenciones de Java)

Comment: No se supone que si el setter y getter es booleano la variable tiene que ser booleana y no int??

Comment: @MerkaChinaMC cual es el valor de "personas" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean setPersonas(int valor){
boolean aRetornar= false;
if(valor>=0){
 //suponiendo que tenes un atributo persona tipo int.
  this.persona=valor;
  aRetornar=true;
}
return aRetornar;
}

/*
*si entra un valor positivo o cero por el parametro "valor" el 
atributo de instancia persona, se modifica al valor ingresado y
retorna verdadero ;
*de lo contrario, no entra en el if y devuelve falso,
*si aun te sigue tirando error, prueba un tester como por ejemplo
*supongamos que este método corresponde a la clase Fiesta  
*y ese método modifica la cantidad de personas de esa fiesta;

*/
//ahora estamos en el main
public static void main(String[] args){
 Fiesta f1= new Fiesta();
 //y acá proba con valores

 if(!fiesta.setPersonas(-1))
   System.out.println("OK- setPersonas(-1) devuelve Falso");
 else
   System.out.println("MAL- setPersonas(-1) devuelve Verdadero");    


 if(fiesta.setPersonas(1))
   System.out.println("OK- setPersonas(1) devuelve Verdadero");
 else
   System.out.println("MAL- setPersonas(1) devuelve Falso");    


 if(fiesta.setPersonas(0))
   System.out.println("OK- setPersonas(0) devuelve Verdadero");
 else
   System.out.println("MAL- setPersonas(0) devuelve Falso"); 

}
/*
*si te sigue tirando error es que el error esta en como recolectas
*el valor desde la consola, si es así me gustaría ver el código
*que hiciste.
```

*/

Comment: Te importaría acompanyar tu respuesta con una pequenya explicacion?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando pides los datos para escribir el número lo haces con:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int nume = sc.nextInt();
//O lo haces con 
String nume = sc.nextLine();
```

Por que aunque aveces el Casteo lo realiza solo el propio java, obviamente no es lo mismo ponerle un numero entero positivo como String y que lo castee el solo a int a la hora de enviarlo a un método, que mandarlo con un guión delante que como es obvio no significa lo mismo si estamos enviando un número que si enviamos un String.

Answer (score -1):

Sobreentiendo que personas es un atributo de la clase en la que estas realizando el método denominado también personas. Si es así y necesitas actualizar el valor del atributo prueba a dejarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
public boolean personas(int valorIntroducido) {

if(valorIntroducido<0) {

    return false;

}else {

    this.personas=valorIntroducido; /*Actualizará el valor del atributo de la clase personas al de valorIntroducido*/
    return true;
}
```

De lo contrario, si no deseas actualizar el valor del atributo de la clase, bastaría con eliminar esa línea:

```
public boolean personas(int valorIntroducido) {

if(valorIntroducido<0) {

    return false;

}else {

    return true;

}
```

Comment: nada sigue igual.. cuando le doy a la opción me entra en el "case" correcto y pongo un numero y todo bien, el problema es cuando pongo un numero negativo que me salta una exception que no tiene nada que ver.